# jquery mobile thumbnail and text alignment in listview

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, jquery-mobile

I have a `listview` element which has thumbnails. The thumbnails are aligned in a special way and text seems to get extra top and bottom spacing. Any ideas how to get the text to align vertically with the image?

Comment: or maybe a link to some code? http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I have gone for to get the image to align perfectly with the top of the text is:

```
<div style="padding:10px 10px 10px 0;text-align:center; float:left;">
   <img src="image.jpg" style="max-width:80px;max-height:80px;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to create a rule for paragraph tags inside of list items that sets the `line-height` of the `p` element to a specific value:

```
.ui-page .ui-content .ui-listview p {
    line-height    : 65px;
    vertical-align : middle;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7fdSJ/2/

If you want to allow multiple lines of text then you can add this:

```
white-space    : normal;
```

But this has the side-affect that each line will occupy `65px` or whatever value you hard-coded for the `line-height` property.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7fdSJ/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-page .ui-content .ui-listview p {
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

Its a hack, but it works. Custom fit the value 10px for your own case.